# Accessing the key of a dictionary with a list of values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Here are the main lists and dictionary that I am trying to work on:

```
Nodes = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
Lengths= [50,60,70]
dic= {'A':[Nodes[0],Lengths[0]],'B':[Nodes[1],Lengths[1]],'C':[Nodes[2],Lengths[2]]}
```

In this example, I am trying to get the key of the dictionary if one item in the values exists. For example, I am expecting to get the key 'A' if I have 50 in the list of values since it is represented as Lengths[0]. so far, I have been working with a function that returns the key if I provided the whole list of values, as follows.

```
def get_key(Val): 
    for key, value in a.items(): 
         if Val == value: 
            return key 

print(get_key([Nodes[0],Lengths[0]]))
```

Help would be appreciated. 
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `==` to `in` and call `print(get_key(Lengths[0]))`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you . I was trying to figure out how to get the key based on an item in a list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by populating a lookup dictionary from the keys and Lengths in your `dic` dictionary.

```py
Nodes = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
Lengths= [50,60,70]
dic= {'A':[Nodes[0],Lengths[0]],'B':[Nodes[1],Lengths[1]],'C':[Nodes[2],Lengths[2]]}

keyByLength = {v[1]: k for k, v in dic.items()}

print(keyByLength[50])
print(keyByLength[60])
print(keyByLength[70])
```

Outputs

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is almost there, you just need to change the lookup to something like this:

```
def get_key(Val): 
    for key, value in dic.items(): 
         if Val in value: 
            return key
```